# How to add the value of this column? (us+ sy+id+wa)

Tags: linux, columns

I want to find for the CPU Utilization. So, I am trying to add the us, sy, id, wa column.Is it possible to do the addition for those 4 column. Any suggestion?

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0  61860 136688      0 714920    0    0     4    14    0    6  1  1 97  0  0
 1  0  61860 136688      0 714920    0    0     0     0  150  145  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0  61860 136696      0 714920    0    0     0     0  108  129  1  0 99  0  1
 0  0  61860 136688      0 714920    0    0     0     0  177  179  0  1 99  0  0
 0  0  61860 136696      0 714920    0    0     0     0  137  155  0  0 100  0  0

expected output:

total utilization
100%
98%
76%
```

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Since you are counting the idle time as well, the actual result will be near 100% all the time. If you want the utilization of the CPU, exclude the idle (id) field from the calculation

Answer (score 1):

You could process the output with awk and add a column with the desired sum.

```
vmstat | awk 'NR<=2{print}NR>2{printf("%s\t%d\n", $0, $13+$14+$15+$16);}'
```

After your "expected output" addition, you could do something like:

```
vmstat | awk '{print}NR>2{us+=$13; sy+=$14; id+=$15; wa+=$16}END{printf("Total us:%d sy:%d id:%d wa:%d\n", us, sy, id, wa);}'
```